# How can an output buffer worsen performance

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am writing a php script and somewhere before my `header()` function i have printed text to the browser hereby causing my `header()` function give me a well known error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

Now my question is, I have the intentions of using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` before and after the `header()` function. But I once heard something like output buffer can affect the performance of one's application negatively. How true is that?

Or should I just stick with the idea of printing Javascript function to redirect the page.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I thank you all very much for your time and positive contributions to my question.now i understand things better, most especially the output buffer that got me confused for a while. After all the posts, i have been able to come with the right approach.thanks guys, you all saved me a lot of thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an output buffer requires the server to store the entire output of the PHP in RAM, so if it's a large page, you'll wind up using a fair amount of memory - and the server will also have to wait until the entire page is generated before sending it out, which could cause a small delay. But other than that, I don't think there's much of a disadvantage in using an output buffer. For what you want to do, it's certainly a reasonable solution.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the data isn't streamed until the ob_flush() is called, which will cause slower load times (but not necessary slower generation times).

Comment: I have a question about the topic, can I what with you [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83235/room-for-sajad-and-david-z) ?

Answer (score 5):

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Test `ob_start` and friends to see if the performance difference matters.  If it does, look for alternatives.

The easiest option is to move the `header()` call before your printing.

As you are likely performing a redirect with something like:

```
header('Location: /new/location/');
```

You should not print anything before this `header()` call because the client wouldn't do anything with the data you printed anyway (unless there's something I'm missing about HTTP).

(Javascript is not a good option for redirects, and nor is `meta` refreshing, unless you want to detect Javascript for some reason.)

Answer (score 2):

Relocating in PHP-code after output can say about bad application design.
But I don't know your situation and can propose two possible ways.

1. Split code into model (data processing) and view (output) (see [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)). This means that you are making decision about relocating even before displaying anything. I'd called this way preferred.
2. If you *really* need to show output (or other headers sent), common way is combining JS and HTML (in noscript):

   ```
   if (headers_sent()) {
       print('<script type="text/javascript">( document.location.replace ) ? document.location.replace("'.$location.'") : document.location.href = "'.$location.'";</script>'."\n".'<noscript><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL='.$location.'" /></noscript>');
   } else {
       header('Location: '.$location);
       exit;
   }
   ```

P.S. This code is a piece of Fusebox framework.

Comment: thanks for the advise. should have applied the MVC technique right from the start of the project.apart from zend framework,which other framework can u recommend? i mean one that will be easy to use.

Comment: Actually, most of popular frameworks force you to use MVC in some form. Also they'll give you a lot of other bonuses, e.g. clean app structure, ORM etc. Examples: http://cakephp.org/ is good but needs some learning to start using, http://codeigniter.com/ seems to be easier to start.

Comment: Oh, and the most important thing imo: even if you'll spend some time now to transfer your existing dev code into framework -- you'll save it back in future.

Answer (score 0):

just answering your last remark: you can redirect the page in php using `header('Location: '.$url)` it should go before any other output obviously and is advised to be followed by `exit();`